# What can cause sound inside computer aside from fan?

Tags: audio, fan

There is a slight whirring sound from inside my laptop. However I realized that even if I unplugged the fan, the sound would still exist. I also have a ssd. Is there any non moving part that could generate this sound?

Comment: providing the model of laptop might help

Comment: Could be an extra fan, perhaps on the GPU, or a faulty MB, or some warming/cooling issue - you did not provide enough information to assist...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some components that can make nose even when they shouldn't:

- small transformer (like the one in display that create high voltage)
- relay - they can clicking
- coil - they can vibrate

But it could be also broken CD-ROM.

Comment: "can make nose" xD